# access Start screen tile space through code in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8

I have a requirement where I want to check if there is an empty tile space on the start screen of windows 8. Is there any way to access this space?

Answer (score 2):

Nope, this is not possible. The start space is intended to be in control of the user, and its layout (rows, visible columns) can change at any time.